# How to automatically "live" synchronize a single file in one direction

Tags: 14.04, scripts, backup

How can I use a script to automatically and immediately update the backup of a single file?

Comment: Use Emacs, it automatically creates backups (stored in the same directory as the original file, with the same name, but with a tilde appended: `file.txt`'s backup's named `file.txt~`)

Comment: So you want to backup file.txt to backup.txt and overwrite file.txt? You can do it with `cat file.txt > backup.txt` and then make your changes to file.txt.

Comment: Hi @YazanMehrez, since you didn't take note of the requests for information; is your question still alive, or abandoned by you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an script (or even an alias) to copy the file before edit it using command cp and --backup=t like this

```
cp --backup=t /path/to/file /path/to/backup.txt
```

to get each time a backup of the file.

If you want everything inside one file named backup.txt you should use

```
cat /path/to/file >> /path/to/backup.txt
```

to attach the current file to backup.txt